# Display random products on homepage with pagination and no duplicates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make the products displaying on my homepage random with pagination, however when i go to the next page, I get duplicates.

I have the code in a custom HTML widget at the moment. It says -

```
[recent_products per_page="30" columns="3" orderby="rand" order=”ASC” paginate="true"]
```

How can I code this so it always loads products in random order, but not duplicate across pages?

(I have seen this question come up a few times with some code to add to the functions.php page, but none of them work)

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: some hosts have disabled `orderby="rand"` - have you checked if it is enabled?

Comment: Hi - How do I do that? It does load randomly each time.. it's just that there's duplicates across pages which I don't want